# Replace all the occurences of a substring in a string leaving the first 2 - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$regex = '([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})';
$string = 'I am emailing to john@gmail.com and hoe@gmail.com but harris@live.com';

$newString = preg_replace($regex,'',$string);
```

I would like to replace all the emails addresses with a empty string leaving the first two.
so the $newString should be 
`I am emailing to john@gmail.com and hoe@gmail.com but`. But in vain.

How do i do it....

Comment: Didn't you ask the pretty much same thing just recently?

Comment: Is your regex working in terms of identifying all email addresses correctly?

Comment: Use preg_replace_callback and keep track of how many replacements were made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As generic answer:

- Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`.
- On the result array, remove every array item with an uneven index, starting after `[4]`.
- Then concatenate the remainder using [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode).

Answer (score -1):

you can try using **explode**

```
 $str = I am emailing to john@gmail.com and hoe@gmail.com but harris@live.com; 
 $str_array = explode( , $str); 
 $counter = 0; 
 $str_out = ; 
 foreach($str_array as $cast){ 
    $findme   = @; 
    $pos = strpos($cast, $findme); 
    if ($pos === false) { 
        $str_out = $str_out . $cast .  ; 
    }else{ 
        $counter++; 
        if($counter<=2){ 
            $str_out = $str_out . $cast .  ; 
        } 
    } 
 } 
 echo $str_out;
```

Comment: Far too complex, plus this removes any "word" that contains @'s not just email addresses.